# JSON shows in browser, but does not load in the html table with DataTables plugin?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I have a simple MVC app which gets data from a database table and displays it in the an html table.  When I tried to use Server Side processing, the data is returned, but it shows in the browser instead  of my table.

Here is the script:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#patients').dataTable({
                    "bServerSide":true,
                    "bProcessing":true,
                    "sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("Index","Patient")',
                    "bJQueryUI": true,
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
                });
            });
</script>
```

Here is the html table:

```
<table width="100%" id="patients">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Here is my controller action method:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Patient> patients = new List<Patient>();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=server;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=True"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FirstName,LastName FROM Patient",conn))
                {
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        patients.Add(new Patient { FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString(), LastName = reader["LastName"].ToString() });
                    }
                }

            }
            return Json(new
            {
                aaData = patients.Select(x=> new[] {x.FirstName,x.LastName})
            },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
```

Here is the JSON that shows in the broswer:

```
{"aaData":[["Tom","Jones"],["Jerry","Jones"],["Jack","Roberts"],["Harry","Truman"],["Bill","Clinton"],["Barrack","Obama"],["George","Bush"],["Ed","Lee"],["Michael","Jordan"],["James","Caan"],["Rick","Reilly"],["Johhny","B.Goode"]]}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("your logo here", "Index", "Home")</p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">
                        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                    </section>
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Patients","Index","Patient")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>


        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/table")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the patients element tag?

Comment: If it is a table element how is it defined?

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso - Sorry, I thought the table was included. It should be in the post now.

Comment: Have you tried without the 100% width?
datatable constructor calculates the width

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso - That did not work.

Comment: Not shure why it isnt working, everything seems well. I'm testing here. Can you give me an example of json data tested?

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso - Upated POST with JSON.

Comment: Are you importing or using any css for that data? Cause here everything worked, the data was injected to the table, the only thing that is left in your description is css to align the data with the table but it is working. Also importing jquery and jquery.datatables of course.

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso, I was using css to style the pagination and using jqueryui theme to style the overall table, but I removed that and it still does not work.  It just shows the plain JSON in the broswer (I am using chrome) instead of in the table.

Comment: It worked here. 
Can you edit and insert the hole html page?

Comment: On which page are you table located ?

Comment: @ChristianDietz - The page is located in Index.cshtml for the PatientController.

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso - I posted the whole index.cshtml page.

Comment: I'm sorry, i wanted to ask html source code, not the view engine code. Also is jquery/datable and your script in bundles/table ?
If you could change the view engine code for html source i think i could get the problems.
Everything worked right here so i think there's a problem with the script import.

Answer (score 0):

You have some options here:

If you have the data for your datatable when you are loading the page, you should probably just use the model to carry the data and enter it into the table.

If you need to load the data asynchronosly, you want to create different actions on your controller - one to load your page (in this case the Index action) and a second one for getting the data for the datatable. What you see is the result of trying to use a single action to do both.

The action for getting the data should look like this:

```
public JsonResult PatientsData()
{
   List<Patient> patients = new List<Patient>() {
      new ListItem() { FirstName= "1", LastName = "VA" }
   };

        return Json(new
        {
            aaData = patients.Select(x=> new[] {x.FirstName,x.LastName})
        },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then you can configure your datatable like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": '~/Controller/PatientsData'
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Hi, I got it to work this way, but have a few questions:  1) Can you elaborate a bit more on why I can't a single action to handle both? 2) When I set the bServerSide to true, it just says processing. Is there a different setup for that? 3) Now that I have my Index action, I am still passing the PatientData model to it as I did before. Is this the proper way to do it?

Comment: @Xaisoft 2) If you want to use bServerSide, you need to implement more than just getting the data. You need stuff like total records, page number, sorting, searching etc. You can read more of the requirements for that here: http://datatables.net/usage/server-side

1) What you shouldn't do is have a single action returning an `ActionResult` (a page) and then have it return a Json. This will return in a page like the one you have/had where the Json is rendered and then the html. While this is possible to work with it is far too troublesome.

Comment: @Xaisoft 3) If you have the dataset up front, you can just pass it to the page using `@model IList<Patient>` in the view, and then create the table in the view like: ScottGu's example here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/19/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor.aspx
Lastly your datatables initiation would be limited to: `$('#example').dataTable()`

Answer (score -1):

Hi You need to Create HTML Table from JSON Result :

```
function CreateDynamicTable(objArray) {
//var array = JSON.parse(objArray);
var array = objArray;
var str = '<table class="display" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="example">';
str += '<thead><tr>';
for (var index in array[0]) {
    str += '<th scope="col">' + index + '</th>';
}
str += '</tr></thead>';
str += '<tbody>';
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    str += (i % 2 == 0) ? '<tr class="gradeA">' : '<tr class="gradeA">';
    for (var index in array[i]) {
            str += '<td>' + array[i][index] + '</td>';
    }
    str += '</tr>';
}
str += '</tbody>'
str += '<tfoot><tr>';
for (var index in array[0]) {
    str += '<th scope="col">' + index + '</th>';
}
str += '</tr></tfoot>';
str += '</table>';
return str;
```

}

Script to create Datatable

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Index/Patient',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        var objlist = JSON.parse(data);
                        //if no Data
                        if (objlist.toString() != '') {
                            var str = CreateDynamicTable(objlist );
                            //Create HTML Table in  DIV
                            $("#bind").html(str);
                            //Create datatable
                            $('#example').dataTable({
                                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"                                    
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            //if no Data
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
```

And Your HTML :

```
<div id="bind">
<table width="100%" id="patients">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
```

Comment: In some examples I have seen, I have not seen a dynamic table created.

Comment: jquery datatable constructor is for that